# Blazor, event on model change in editform

Tags: blazor

I've got a table with controls bound to a model, and I need to call a function when some of these controls' values change. (Recalculating totals and taxes)

The table is in an edit form, and the controls are bound to the model, so I cannot use the onchange event in the controls.

What I've tried:

- use the SetParametersAsync or OnParametersSetAsync functions, however it only gets triggered when the model is set the first time, not on each change of a property in the model as I would expect.
- tried to use the set accessor of the model, however doing this and running in debug the browser crashes and in my debug console I get a access violation error with no context:

  private Order order 
   {
    get { return order; }
    set {
         order = value;
         CalculateTotals();
       } 
   }

> The program '[11992] iisexpress.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>   The program '[11992] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
 <EditForm EditContext="@EditContext">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="amount">Amount: </label>
        <InputNumber Id="amount" Class="form-control" @bind- 
                                         Value="@Model.Amount"> 
        </InputNumber>
             <ValidationMessage For="@(() => Model.Amount)" />

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="items">Items: </label>
    <InputNumber Id="items" Class="form-control" @bind-Value="@Model.Items"> 
    </InputNumber>
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => Model.Items)" />
    </div>

</EditForm>


@code
{
    private EditContext EditContext;
    private Order Model = new Order();


    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        EditContext = new EditContext(Model);
        EditContext.OnFieldChanged += EditContext_OnFieldChanged;

        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    private void EditContext_OnFieldChanged(object sender, 
                                                      FieldChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.FieldIdentifier.FieldName);

         if (EditContext.Validate())
         {
            // You can validate the EditContext here, and do necessary 
            calculation 
         }

    }

    }
```

Hope this helps...

Update:

I've never done it before, but let me suggest the following: Define your child component as follows:

### ChildComponent.razor

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="item">Item: </label>

 <select id="Item" class="form-control-sm" @bind="@Model.Item">
    @foreach (var item in items)
    {
        <option value="@item">@item</option>

    }
</select>

<ValidationMessage For="@(() => Model.Item)" />

</div>

@code
{

   [Parameter]
   public Order Model { get; set; }
}
```

In the parent component, insert the following within the EditForm

Now, you can perform various operations in the child component, as if its code is within the EditForm.

Note: I hope this work... never done it before, and of course I did not execute this code...

Note: You have to provide a list of items here, either pass it from the parent component as a Component Parameter or create a list of items in the the child component, retrieve from database, etc.

Comment: One thing to add here.  It seems that this isn't working for bound custom controls.  I've got a custom control with a dropdown in it.  I can see that my event callbacks are working fine with its value if I assign it to a var outside of the model (I can see that set is being called from the child), however the onfieldchanged event isn't firing for the child control.  anything else I am missing?

Comment: Thanks enet, I'm going to try this.

Comment: Hi enent... Could get it to work so to rule out any errors, added the select directly into the editform....  it still isn't triggering the on change event above... thinking something might be wrong with the select...but can't see anything obvious.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @ if (line.Taxes != null)
      {
         foreach (var tax in line.Taxes)
          { 
              <select id="tax-@tax.TaxCodeId" @bind="tax.TaxCodeId" class="form-control">
                    @ if (taxCodes != null)
                        {
                           foreach (var taxcode in taxCodes)
                              {
                                 <option value="@taxcode.Id">@taxcode.Name</option>
                               }
                         }
                </select>


          }
   }

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't react previously. I really meant that you should use the InputSelect and not the select element in the child component, though you can derive from either  to provide for additional functionality.  I saw that you've posted another question related to this. I did not review the greatest part of the code, but I guess the answer you've got solved your issues, though I don't see what the answer has added. Good luck.